# Changing the name of my solid state drive

Tags: partitioning, devices

I have a new machine, running 18.04 and the drive has the excruciating name `nvme0n1` and partitions I've created are named, eg.,`/dev/nvnme0n1p6`.    This is completely impossible to remember.  In the good old days of 16.04 the drive was simply named `/dev/sda` and partitions were named `/dev/sda6`  etc. Easily memorized.  I don't know whether this is a hardware thing or a software thing.     If the latter, is it possible to rename the device back to `/dev/sda` and then have partitions be numbered, once again, `/dev/sda6`, etc?      I've played around on `gparted` but can't find an option that will enable me to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could adapt https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281402/70524. That said, how often do you even need to remember the nvme0n1 prefix? Tab completion is a thing.

Comment: Should be using UUIDs and those are even worse, or you always have to copy from terminal command. Or use labels which I do use a lot for partitions I only want to mount occasionally.

Comment: Thanks for these responses.     It seems when I'm setting up a new machine that I'm using these labels constantly.     Looked like `sudo e2label /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/sda` would be a very easy way of doing it, but it seemed to have zero effect.   The other alternative I tried was to create symbolic links as per post 70524.      But that required knowing how to fill in `ATTRS(model)` and `ATTRS(serial)` which I couldn't figure out how to do.